# apache + django +wsgi_mod server, can't startup application from client server

Tags: python, django, apache

When the Django application is in development mode, I can start the application on the server through the WEB page, but I cannot startup the application through the WEB page after deploying the Django application on Apache. I found the application process loaded, but the application cannot pop-up interface.

I create process startup the application with the following code:

```
commond = ur"pybot.bat D:\Test\pagePerformance\1-testCase\pagePerformance-ie.txt"
msgtmp = sub.Popen(commond,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide the version of your OS type and version, Database type and version, Python type and version, Django type and version.

Comment: OK,my OS is Win7 64bit, Database is Mysql ,the version of Mysql is  5.7.15, I use Python 2.7.12 and django 1.11. The version of Apache is 2.4,thank you.